# How do I find the text in column C where column A is "Riker Farm" and column B is "cow" in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

So column A is the farms (Riker Farm, Sunshine Meadows, Open Peaks, etc.). Column B is the item (cow, pig, pumpkin, etc.). Column C is the weight of the item on that farm. I need to output the weight of the cow on Riker Farm in a different cell.

I tried using vlookup, but I couldn't figure out how to combine the requirements to find the cell that matched both. Especially since the farms and items repeat. I know this search could be done manually, but I was hoping to save some time since this is going to have to be looked up many times for many criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=FILTER(C:C, 
 (A:A="Riker Farm")*(B:B="cow"))
```

##### [FILTER Function ➚](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197)

Returns a filtered version of the source range, returning only rows or columns that meet the specified conditions